# Disable only XmlOrderAttribute in xsd2Code

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd2code

I'm using xsd2Code and I want to disable xml order while keeping the attributes.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<OrderXMLAttrib>Tue/False</OrderXMLAttrib>
```

Add this into configuration file (filespecified/generatedcode/defaultconfig) or change the value throught the UI when call xsd2code.